# How to detect if click event is finished in android?

Tags: android, event-handling, touch, onclicklistener, android-event

I create views dynamically, and I handle their click events normally, like this :

```
myView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xaaffffff);


            }
        });
```

But this code does not handle the `onRelease` event, so the view remains with white background, after the click.

So how can I set the background to another value when the clicked state is over ?

Thanks in advance !

### Edit:

`OnTouchListener` does the exact same thing. I guess I need something like `onReleaseListener` ?

Comment: You need to set the onTouchListener() instead

Comment: Or you define your drawable with a xml

Comment: @A.S. yes that's a good idea. But I want to learn to program it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you need to use an `onTouchListener` => [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Refer this [tutorial](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/3279/android-the-basics-32-androids-ontouchlistener-and-motionevent/) on how to use this.

Example:

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(
        new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View myView, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {
                myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {
                myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, simple and beautiful. Thanks :) I will accept this. But any ideas on how to do this with transitions ?

Comment: And one little problem, ACTION_UP does not fire, after DOWN + MOVE. Any workaround for this ?

Comment: @mobilGelistirici try to return `true` instead of `false` in the `onTouch` function. See edited answer. Returning `true` means you are consuming the event, therefore you will get the subsequent events.

Comment: Still no success. I asked a different question about that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932482/android-action-up-does-not-get-fired-after-action-move accepting your answer now. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Ok thanks. Good luck with it. I would suggest to return true when you are consuming the event... You are not far from the right thing to do

Answer (score 2):

Android has a selector for this. Define it in a xml file in your drawable folder and use it as background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/YOURDRAWABLE" />           

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/YOURDRAWABLE_WHEN_CLICKED" />          

</selector>
```

Check the [DOCUMENTATION](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will upvote you. But as I said, this is not my answer.

Comment: ok, then use the onTouchListener with different events. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

State lists are meant to be for style updates on state changes. Check this out.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to go for such cómplicated method for capturing a "click" event. Just for this method :-

//Inside on touch listener of course :-

KOTLIN :-

```
    if(event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && event.action != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
// Click has been made...
// Some code
}
```

JAVA :-
Just replace event.action with event.getAction()

This works for me