# Android ACTION_UP does not get fired after ACTION_MOVE

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I'm trying to create a view programmatically, and change its background according to its click state.

I know I can do this with xml drawables, but I want to learn to program it too.

But if I press on my view, then slide my finger, the view gets stuck in pressed state. (white =  0xaaffffff background)

My code is this :

### Edit:

I solved the problem. Here is the working code :

```
mainContainer.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {             
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                v.setBackgroundColor(0xaaffffff);                   
                return false;
            }               

            if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
            {                   

            }

            if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
            {                  
                v.setBackgroundColor(0x00ffffff);
            }

            if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            {               
                v.setBackgroundColor(0x00ffffff);                   
                return true;
            }


            return false;

        }
    });
```

As you see, I tried returning true wherever I want `onTouch()` to be called again. But apparently there is something I do not understand here.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What about returning true in your ACTION_UP aswell?

```
if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)

    {               
      v.setBackgroundColor(0x00ffffff);
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too. still no success. updated the question.

Comment: And if you return false in your ACTION_MOVE ?

Comment: oh. should I return true only in ACTION UP, and return false when I want to re-call the onTouch function ?

Comment: I think you should just keep it in your ACTION_DOWN, if you can give a try.

Comment: I'm trying all combinations whenever I'm not writing here :) still no success though.. I'm really confused about true and false. Which one stops the onTouch, which one continues it ?

Comment: It's not clear for me neither but check this link :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756383/what-is-meaning-of-boolean-value-returned-from-an-event-handling-method-in-andro

Comment: hehe :) I just closed that. And I solved my problem, by setting the background also in ACTION_CANCEL event. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Glad you went through this one ! was kind of confused too :)